# Case-insensitive version of array_search()

Tags: php, arrays, filtering, case-insensitive

I have an array like this:

```
$array = ['oooo', 'no', 'mmmm', 'yes'];
```

I'd like to search for a  word "yes". I know about `array_search()`, but I'd like to match "yes", "Yes" and "YES" as well.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
array_search(strtolower($search), array_map('strtolower', $array));
```

Comment: Be aware, array_map('strtolower' ... is not working with Cyrillic characters! Probably with utf-8 as a whole, except the Latin ones.

Comment: @NikolayIvanov depends on the locale: [php.net/strtolower](http://php.net/strtolower). If you don't want to depend on OS locale, your best bet is [mb_strtolower](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php), which is of course not enough: see for example [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php#108346). Since PHP doesn't have locale aware string functions like Java or C#, you have to implement your own string classes/functions according to your needs :) This is one of the areas where "UTF-8 everything" doesn't fix everything...

Comment: Beware, if the value of your array keys matter (which they often do), this won't work because  `array_map` will renumber from 0. So the returned value will have no meaning.

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer of what use would be the position of the element for this usage?

Comment: @HalilÖzgür For the question asked, it probably doesn't matter since the keys appear to be generic. But people often assign specific key values to an arrayt, e.g. packageId => package name. And if you search a package name, you want to get the ID of that package.

Comment: @ChadwickMeyer The remapping of the keys does not always happen I've noticed.

Comment: To the down-voter: would you mind sharing the reason? I'm just wondering :)

Comment: I am using PHP 7.0.15 and still the keys are not remapped, so if you do use the keys as the ID reference for something, you're fine. :)

Comment: Just to clarify the array_map key issue:  array_map never renumbers when there is only one array argument, and always renumbers when there are more than one.  This behavior is clearly documented in the manual.  So the solution as presented will always retain the original key.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `in_array()` instead of `array_search()`.

```
$response = in_array('yes', array_map('strtolower', $array));
```

Comment: Note: user comment on PHP website states that `in_array` might give more predictable results doing a "strict" search adding `true` as third parameter: `$is_there = in_array('yes', array_map('strtolower', $array), true);`.

Comment: That's why the `array_map('strtolower', $array)` it's there, to normalize the entire array to lower case.

Comment: This depends on what the expected result should be.

Comment: @brunohdaniel it's not only about caseing, it depends on the values of the array. Anyway take a look at [the comment I mentioned above](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#106319), it's pretty interesting (now I can link it, there was no permalink at the time).

Answer (score 1):

It is unnecessary and inefficient to convert the case of all values in the haystack for an iterative task which may stop as soon as a qualifying value is found.  Use a conditionally broken loop. [Demo](https://3v4l.org/AkIGYk)

```
$array = ['oooo', 'no', 'mmmm', 'yes'];
$needle = 'Yes';

foreach ($array as $i => $v) {
    if (stripos($v, $needle) !== false) {
        $found = $i;
        break;
    }
}
echo $found ?? 'Not found';
// output: 3
```

---

If you want to minimize globally scoped variables, perform the loop inside of an [Immediately Invoked Functional Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35044452/2943403). [Demo](https://3v4l.org/CFXbX)

```
echo (function($haystack, $needle) {
          foreach ($haystack as $i => $v) {
              if (stripos($v, $needle) !== false) {
                  return $i;
              }
          }
          return null;
      })($array, $needle) ?? 'Not found';
// output: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry, I see it's for values, see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php#88648

---

For keys:

```
$a = array('YES', 'yes', 'Yes'); 
$b = array_change_key_case($a, CASE_LOWER); 
$f = array_search(strtolower($search), $b);
```

Comment: I mentioned yes for example ..but i like to search any word in array

Comment: @Ashley - this is good for single byte, any suggestion for multi-byte?

Comment: @gowri change $search to whatever you want to search for

Comment: @ajreal are you talking about keys or values? This might help http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-change-key-case.php#82522

Comment: @Ashley - values, what if the value is a multi-byte?

Comment: Use the function linked to in the answer and then use http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php instead

Comment: `array_change_key_case()` makes absolutely no sense on an indexed array.