# Insert 0 into variable if weeknumber is not filled

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

For my admin page I created a graph which shows my registerd members per week for 2016 and 2015.

The Mysql query is working fine but when in a certain week no members has registerd the graph just moves one position to the left.

Mysql query

```
    SELECT WEEKOFYEAR( date) AS weekno, COUNT( 1 ) AS signup, 
           SUBDATE( date, INTERVAL WEEKDAY( date) DAY ) AS date_of_week
    FROM members
    WHERE YEAR( date) = '".$year."'
    GROUP BY WEEKOFYEAR( date);
```

What I (asume) need to do is check the array for missing weekno and if so fill the (new?) array with the missing weekno and add value 0 to signups.

```
foreach($oMember as $val) {
    $signups = $val[signups];
    $weekno = $val[weekno];
    if(empty($val)) { $val = '0'; }
}
```

This is what I tried but stil without any good working solution, also [array search](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4170079/1792782) from Halil:

```
 array_search(strtolower($search), array_map('strtolower', $array));
```

Hope someone can help.

Best regards. 
Jan

Comment: If there is no data for a specific `weekno` then there will be no row returned for that `weekno` so testing for an `empty($val)` is a waste of time

Comment: You will have to check that the `weekno` is contiguous and where rows for any week number are not present fake one into your data that you pass to the graph

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks, but how to check for contiguous or how to add these values?