# array_search in php doesn't find my string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I'm trying to make a function that searches a string in a whole array. But it give me anything... So my array looks like this :

```
    array:1 [▼
      "list" => array:2 [▼
        "pagination" => array:5 [▶]
        "entries" => array:11 [▼
          0 => array:1 [▼
            "entry" => array:8 [▼
              "firstName" => "Doctor"
              "lastName" => "Who"
              "emailNotificationsEnabled" => true
              "telephone" => "0123456789"
              "company" => []
              "id" => "DW"
              "enabled" => true
              "email" => "doctorwho@time.lord"
            ]
          ]
          1 => array:1 [▶]
          2 => array:1 [▶]
          3 => array:1 [▶]
          4 => array:1 [▶]
          5 => array:1 [▶]
          6 => array:1 [▶]
          7 => array:1 [▶]
          8 => array:1 [▶]
          9 => array:1 [▶]
          10 => array:1 [▶]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

So for exemple at first I did `$key = array_search("doctor", $users);` but this gives me nothing. So I thought it was because I have a multidimensional array. So I reduced it to just one array (and I would search in the rest of the original array with a for loop), so now I'm working with this array that I got with `$users['list']['entries'][0]`

```
array:1 [▼
  "entry" => array:8 [▼
    "firstName" => "Doctor"
    "lastName" => "Who"
    "emailNotificationsEnabled" => true
    "telephone" => "0123456789"
    "company" => []
    "id" => "DW"
    "enabled" => true
    "email" => "doctorwho@time.lord"
  ]
]
```

But `$key = array_search("doctor", $users['list']['entries'][0]);` still doesn't give me anything (but false).

Does anyone know where is my mistake ? Because I couldn't find a solution of my problem yet and it's been a pretty long time I'm on it... I'm still a beginner in php so maybe I've missed something obvious and i'm sorry if I did.

Thank you in advance !

Comment: First, your array is still multi-dimensional. You need `$users['list']['entries'][0]['entry']`. Second, `array_search` only finds exact, case-sensitive matches, and none of the values in the array are "doctor".

Comment: @iainn Oh ok thank you ! Even if you add false like that `array_search("value", $array, false)`?

Comment: Yep. `false` is the default behaviour, so you don't ever need to explicitly pass it. You generally want to provide `true` in most cases anyway, since otherwise you'll get false positives when comparing strings to boolean true. In this case, if you run `array_search("doctor", $array, false)`, it will match the `emailNotificationsEnabled` field.

Comment: @iainn Ok with `$key = array_search("Doctor", $users['list']['entries'][0]['entry']);` it works and displays me firstName but when i put false you're right it always gives me `emailNotificationsEnabled` with whatever value i use. So how can I search something in my array without case sensitivity ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168107/case-insensitive-array-search

Comment: @iainn thank you a lot !

Comment: @JackA check my answer, i updated my answer to make your search case in-sensetive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are searching for `doctor`,but value stored in your array is as `Doctor`. So either search for `Doctor` as

```
$key=array_search('Doctor', $users['list']['entries'][0]));
```

or for case in-sensetive search use

```
$key=array_search(strtolower('Doctor'), array_map('strtolower', $users['list']['entries'][0]));
```

> Note: as your array is multidimensional, so use loop to search your value

Comment: Disabling the `strict` option doesn't mean that the search is case-insensitive.

Comment: Ok first I've forgotten the `['entry']` to make my array unidimensional so I now use `$users['list']['entries'][0]['entry']` which works with a case-sensitive search , thats one big problem solved I guess aha But for the case in-sensetive search I always get this error `Warning: strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` whatever I do. Do you know where that comes from ?

Comment: Ok I know why it gives me this error :  it is because of `"company"` which is an array.. I'll open another issue if I can't find how to solve this since it is another problem thank you !