# Array case-insensitive adding to it removing the spaces, strtolower not enough to work correctly in this case

Tags: php, arrays

Is it possible to do case-insensitive following by removing spaces when do search in an array

So with a source array like this:

```
$a= array(
 'Especificação do instrumento :',
 'especificação do instrumento : ',
 'Especificação do Instrumento :',
 'Especificação do Instrumento : '
```

);

The following lookups would all return true:

```
in_array('Especificação do instrumento :', $a);
in_array('especificação do instrumento : ', $a);
in_array('Especificação do Instrumento :', $a);
in_array('Especificação do Instrumento : ', $a);
```

What function or set of functions would do the same? I don't think `in_array` with `strtolower` can do this.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sepehr/6351397

Comment: guys I already test it, but because have spaces strtolower not working file!

Comment: Use `trim` with `strtolower`

Comment: Did you give up???

Answer (score 0):

Use this answer [Case-insensitive array search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4168107/case-insensitive-array-search) and add `trim` to the value and each array element:

```
array_search(trim(strtolower($search)), array_map(function($v) {
                                                      return trim(strtolower($v));
                                                  }, $array));
```

This handles spaces at the beginning and end.  To handle multiples in the middle you would need to `preg_replace` multiple spaces with one.

Comment: thank you to let me remember `preg_replace` .. i added the code that fit my problem, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

used:

```
$key = array_search(strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '', "Especificação do instrumento :")), array_map('strtolower', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $array)));
```